# Where to declare global variable? in .h or.m?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, global-variables

Whats difference between declaring variable in .m file bellow @implementation and in .h fie in @interface??

```
@implementation PiechartViewController
NSMutableArray *impIDs;
```

I observed if i create 3 objects of piechartViewController new object overwrites previous object data i.e impIDs of 3 different object has same value that of last instantiated object.

instead if I followed this way

in ".h" file

```
@interface PiechartViewController : UIViewController {
    NSMutableArray * impIDs;
```

Code works properly.Means impIDs has 3 different values.

Comment: your post needs editing. Use the {} for codes, etc...

Comment: Post a code with proper format. add the comment

Answer (score 2):

First, class names start with uppercase letters and instance variables start with lower case letters.  It is convention.

```
@implementation PiechartViewController
NSMutableArray *impIDs;
```

In the above, `impIDs` is a variable that is defined within the scope of the file containing that code.  While it is a global, more or less, you won't be able to access it from other files without declaring it somewhere that is visible to them (something like `extern NSMutableArray *impIDs`).

```
@interface PiechartViewController : UIViewController {
    NSMutableArray * impIDs;
```

Here, `impIDs` is an instance variable and, thus, each instance will have storage for it's own isolated bit of data accessible in the `impIDs` instance variable slot.

I'd suggest you [read this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html).

Comment: i revert few of your changes just to reflect the fact that both declaration are for same thing but done it in different ways

Comment: Mmm... K.  That kinda made my answer wrong.  Edited so your edits will no longer cause confusion. :)